# Mobile browser camera access

Tags: mobile, html5-video

HeIIo, I was reading lot's of articles and answers regarding this topic; however most of them are way outdated.
On my website I utilize webcam functionality with:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
```

Yet, this will not work on any mobile browser. Is there a way to stream video and take snapshots within a mobile browsers (at least some of them)? Thank you.